# Does Android AnimationSet override duration and interpolator to child animations?

Tags: android, animation

I have two different animations :

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0f,1f);
alphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);
alphaAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f,2f,1f,2f);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(3000);
scaleAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

And  i need to play this to animations synchronously.

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);
set.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
set.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
set.setDuration(5000);
startAnimation(set);
```

And i have a question. I set some values such as **interpolator** and **duration** on each animation. Does AnimationSet ***affect(override)*** interpolator value when i setting it on AnimationSet? This question also to *duration* value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and yes. 
AnimationSet does override the duration value of the "child" animations. This is mentioned in the docs and I also tested to confirm. setInterpolator is not mentioned explicitly, but I tested that as well, and it overrode the interpolated value of all the child animations as well.